# Drop a column from a Range Partitioned and Compressed table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with data and need to remove a column, which is marked as unused. But it gives the error due to the compressed table.

I have used the command

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> MOVE NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4;
```

But it gives this error:

> ORA-14511: cannot perform operation on a partitioned object

How can I disable the partitioned? And how can I remove the unused column?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot `move` partitioned table with one `alter table` statement, you need to perform relocation of that table into a new segment partition by partition:

Create test table:

```
SQL>  create table t1(
  2      col1 number,
  3       col2 number
  4    )
  5    partition by range(col1) (
  6      partition p_1 values less than (10) compress,
  7      partition p_2 values less than (20) compress
  8    );

Table created.
```

Populate test table with some sample data:

```
SQL> insert into t1(col1, col2)
  2      select level
  3           , level
  4        from dual
  5     connect by level <= 3;

3 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

      COL1       COL2        
---------- ----------      
         1          1      
         2          2    
         3          3
```

Drop column statement fails:

```
SQL> alter table t1 drop column col2;
alter table t1 drop column col2
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-39726: unsupported add/drop column operation on compressed tables
```

Table relocation fails:

```
SQL> alter table t1 move nocompress;
alter table t1 move nocompress
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14511: cannot perform operation on a partitioned object
```

Perform relocation of each partition:

```
SQL> alter table t1 move partition p_1 nocompress;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t1 move partition p_2 nocompress;

Table altered.
```

When there are too many partitions, you can easily generate `alter table` statements while querying `user_tab_partitions` data dictionary view. For example:

```
SQL> column res format a50
SQL> select 'alter table '   || t.table_name ||
  2         ' move partition ' || t.partition_name ||
  3         ' nocompress;' as res
  4    from user_tab_partitions t
  5  where t.table_name = 'T1';

RES                                              
--------------------------------------------------  
alter table T1 move partition P_1 nocompress;   
alter table T1 move partition P_2 nocompress;
```

After you have moved all partitions with `nocompress` option, you can drop column(s) issuing:

```
alter table t1 drop column col2
```

statement, or

```
alter table t1 drop unused columns
```

statement, if you already marked column(s) as unused before relocation.

Dropping unused columns:

Make `col2` unused

```
SQL> alter table t1 set unused(col2);

Table altered.
```

List tables with unused columns in our schema

```
SQL> column table_name format a5
SQL> column table_name format a5
SQL> select *
  2    from user_unused_col_tabs;

TABLE      COUNT  
----- ----------        
T1             1
```

Relocate partitions

```
SQL> alter table T1 move partition P_1 nocompress;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table T1 move partition P_2 nocompress;

Table altered.
```

Drop unused columns:

```
SQL> alter table t1 drop unused columns;

Table altered.
```

Make sure we dropped everything we wanted to drop. `Col2` is gone:

```
SQL> desc t1;

Name     Null?    Type
-------- -------- -----------
COL1              NUMBER
```

There are no tables with unused columns:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from user_unused_col_tabs;

no rows selected
```